# I'm creating a pokedex using JS, but I'm having trouble adding another line if the pokemon has more than one type

Tags: javascript

In my pokedex using pokeAPI when adding pokemons of only 1 type, it works perfectly, but when adding a pokemon of two types, I receive an error

```
.then(function(json) {
    nome.innerText = json.name;
    type.innerText = json.types[0].type.name;
   imagem.src = json.sprites.front_default;
 })
```

I tried using IF, I don't know if it's allowed within .then, but if the pokemon doesn't have more than 1 type, I get an error in the console saying that type 2 is undefined.I'm learning, so forgive me for any silly mistakes.

```
.then(function(json) {
    nome.innerText = json.name;
     type.innerText = json.types[0].type.name;
     if (json.types[1].type.name !== 'undefined') {
         type.innerText = json.types[1].type.name;
     }
     imagem.src = json.sprites.front_default;
     })
```

Comment: Probably erroring on `types[1]` being undefined, in which case you can either check if it's undefined beforehand or use null-propagation (i.e. `?.type` ). Also, to compare with undefined, you use `!== undefined`, not the string value.

Comment: Don't put undefined inside commas : undefined === 'undefined' is false

Comment: your problem was fixed? if my answer is correct, please confirm this with the check

Answer (score 0):

details to fix and possible codes:

#### Details

In this part of code:

```js
if (json.types[1].type.name !== 'undefined') {
    type.innerText = json.types[1].type.name;
}
```

1. You check the `json.types[1].type.name`, but if your `json.types` array only have one type, the `json.types[1]` is `undefined` (directly `undefined` without quotes) and `.type` from undefined will generates error.
2. You compare with `'undefined'`: if you use quotes, you are compared with the string instead of `undefined`
3. You replace the text in `type.innerText` with the `type[1].type.name` and ignore the `type[0]` when you have more than one type

#### Fixes or possible code:

1. Fix the if and innerText, you can use:

```js
if (json.types[1] !== undefined) {
    type.innerText = type.innerText + json.types[1].type.name;
}
```

2. New code:

```js
.then(function(json) {
    nome.innerText = json.name;
    type.innerText = json.types.map(function(typeObj) {
        return typeObj.type.name
    }).join(', ');
    imagem.src = json.sprites.front_default;
})
```

Or with other syntax:

```js
.then(json => {
    nome.innerText = json.name;
    type.innerText = json.types.map(typeObj => typeObj.type.name).join(', ');
    imagem.src = json.sprites.front_default;
})
```

If you have other questions, add a comment

PS: you can use if inside `then` code block, it is a normal code block, you can use all the js code.